Deployement Error Could not resolve "./card.svelte" from "src/lib/components/ui/card/index.ts"
I am working on a SvelteKit project with shadcn-svelte and on the components/ui directory all the component exports from index.ts files has this error
Could not resolve "./card.svelte" from "src/lib/components/ui/card/index.ts"

and the Svelte component is right there. It works locally and build locally but when pushed to production this error shows up on the build and won't deploy the app.
It happened on Cloudflare and I tried deploying to Vercel and the same thing happened.
I also noticed that the shadcn-svelte library changed their component names form Uppercase to Lowercase and this might cause the error but I pushed to production after changing the names.
I tried everything I know and please help me if you can!
Here is my tsconfig.json
{
    "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.svelte"]
}

and svelte.config.js
import adapter from "@sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare";
import { vitePreprocess } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config}*/
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            routes: {
                include: ["/*"],
                exclude: ["<all>"],
            },
            platformProxy: {
                configPath: "wrangler.toml",
                environment: undefined,
                experimentalJsonConfig: false,
                persist: false,
              },
        }),
        alias: {
            "@/*": "./path/to/lib/*",
        },
    },
    shadcn: {
        componentPath: "./src/lib/components/ui",
    },
};
export default config;


if this makes any difference, the docs says to import this way import * as Card from "$lib/components/ui/card"

I turned every component into that import format, but it even gives the error for Badge too.  Could not resolve "./badge.svelte" from "src/lib/components/ui/badge/index.ts"

Can the problem be that the file card.svelte has been named with an uppercase C, but index.js tries to import it with a lowercase c? If so, it will still work on Windows, but not on Linux or Mac.

It was like that before. That's how it came with the UI library and they changed it later to lowercase. But I updated the components way before I pushed to production. I had the same problem with my personal portfolio site, But It got fixed after renaming. This is kinda odd

It's working perfectly on my PC. I want to go Production soon as possible
